# Regex to match links but not images or youtube videos

Tags: php, regex

I need to match any valid links separately from links to images and youtube videos. I'd like to put anchor tags around regular links but img and iframe tags around images and youtube videos respectively.

Here's my code

```
$str = "some stuff with links"

    $output = preg_replace('#(http://([^\s]*)\.(jpg|gif|png))#', 
                    '<img src="$1" alt="" width="" height="" />', $str);



    $output = preg_replace('#(http://([^\s]*)youtube\.com/watch\?v=([^\s]*))#', 
                  '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>', $output);

    var_dump($output);
```

This ignores regular links, how do I modify it to detect links but not the other two? Is there a simpler way?

Thanks

Comment: you *could* write a regex to match all 3, then in the callback (use `preg_replace_callback`) then test for the first two cases, and if both fail, do whatever you want with the 3rd regular-link case.

Answer (score 1):

Use two negative lookbehind assertions.

```
/^(http:\/\/([^\s]*)(?<!\.(?:jpg|gif|png))(?<!youtube\.com\/watch\?v=\w{11}))$/
```

Or, using `#` as the delimiter,

```
#^(http://([^\s]*)(?<!\.(?:jpg|gif|png))(?<!youtube\.com/watch\?v=\w{11}))$#
```

Note that negative lookbehind assertions can't have variable-length wildcards.  So, one must expect a rule, *e.g.* "YouTube videos are identified by an 11-character string."

Here is a [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/kZo3TqSJjp).